# Replace folder path into html content

Tags: php, mysql

I have html content into mysql database and my content like this:

```
 ...
        </p>
        <br />
        <b><span class="iasHeader4">empor. Odio in purus enim diam arcu urna 
        aenean, urna mid tincidunt.
        </p>
        <p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <img alt="" class="contentimage left" 
         src="/uploads/2011/08/25/sector_9238247437812ABig.jpg" 
         title=" Lectus elit a placerat," />
        <b><span class="iasHeader4"> Lectus elit a placerat</span></b></p>
        <p>
    ....
```

I want to all content field replace file path. for example:

```
/uploads/2011/08/25/sector_9238247437812ABig.jpg
```

to

```
/media/uploads/sector_9238247437812ABig.jpg
```

I want to strip date folders. (2011/08/25 like this)

**Note:** My old file path structure is `/uploads/Year/Month/Day/FileName` and new file path structure is `/media/uploads/fileName`

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you....
since m beginner in php, don't give bad comment if mah answer is nt good....

```
<?php
    $oldPath="/uploads/Year/Month/Day/FileName";
    $a=explode('/',$oldPath);

    $newPath=($a[1].'/media/'.$a[5]);
?>
```